# Find public folder path none relatively

Tags: javascript, node.js, public

How am I able to get the public folders path whilst calling from any folder inside the tree.

When setting publicFolder as a local in my `express.js` it will output:

```
__dirname + '/public' //c:\var\www\beta.mayfieldafc.com\config/public/
```

If I called it from inside `/app/jade/players` it would output

```
__dirname + '/public' //c:\var\www\beta.mayfieldafc.com\app\jade\players/public/
```

I would just like to be able to reference `public` from anywhere in my site.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use __dirname (which gives you the dir name of where the module is located), and just use relative paths (which gives you the dir path of where the "main" code is located).

```
'./public'
```

That should give you a consistent path regardless of submodule pathing.

Comment: So there is no way to sset a variable that does this. Dam, I wanted to just call locals.public! :(